# Class is not abstract and does not override abstract method valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent) in ListSelectionListener

Tags: java, overriding

I keep getting an overriding error, even though I have used the ListSelectionListener after implementing it.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class TPCGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener, ListSelectionListener {

...

public void diaryPanel()
{
  String data[][] = { {"101","Standard","New brakes","£15.99","2","","N/A","1"} };

String column[] = {"Customer ID","Service Type","Changes Made","Price","Time Taken (hours)","Extra Notes","Agreement Date","Job ID"};

final JTable diaryTable = new JTable(data,column);          
diaryTable.setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
ListSelectionModel select = diaryTable.getSelectionModel();
            select.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
select.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener()
{

     public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e)
     {
       String Data = null;
       int[] row = diaryTable.getSelectedRows();
       int[] columns = diaryTable.getSelectedColumns();
       for(int i = 0; i < row.length; i++)
       {
         for(int j = 0; j < columns.length; j++)
         {
       Data = (String) diaryTable.getValueAt(row[i],columns[j]);
         }
  }

}
});
```

This is the exact error I'm getting:

```
error: TPCGUI is not abstract and does not override abstract method valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent) in ListSelectionListener
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You used a `ListSelectionListener` that is an anonymous class.  You never implemented (different word from "used") that interface on `TCPGUI`.  Based on your code show, I'd guess that you just need to remove `ListSelectionListener` from the list of interfaces that `TCPGUI` implements.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you didn't implement the `ActionListener, ListSelectionListener` interface methods. 
You either have to remove them or just add these methods in your code.

```
@Override // This implements ListSelectionListener
public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
    // Do whatever you want here

}

@Override // ActionListener
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // Do whatever you want here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with this line

```
public class TPCGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener, ListSelectionListener {
```

Your TPCGUI class does not implement the method